# Amount Split across months based on conditions

Tags: excel

I am working on an excel exercise where I need to find the expected revenue based on the deals closed in a particular fiscal year. The fiscal year starts from 1 june and ends on 31 May. eg: FY24 would be 1 June 2023-31 May 2024.

Now, in the attached example, I have project start and end date in columns Q & R.I have calculated the days in each fiscal year (formula : =SUM((SEQUENCE($R4-$Q4, 1, $Q4)>=V$1)*(SEQUENCE($R4-$Q4, 1, $Q4)<=V$2))). Column T is the amount I need to split.

Conditions:
#1 - If column V says 365/366, then Column T should spread across June - May and the amount would be  T4*Y1,T4*z1.... (excel row 4)

#2 - If column V says less than 365/366 and the start date is from the mid of the month and also not from June, then it should consider that and split accordingly. Eg: In row 5, the date is starting from 15 June, so June section should multiple T5*15 and not Y1 and should split it from June - May

#3 - If column Q says starts from October,2023, then June to September should be left blank and the money should be split from october onwards .Eg: T6*1,T6*Z1... (because only 1 day in October and not Y1) - excel row 6

#4 - If start date falls before 1 June 2023, but still there are days in FY24 - how to do it?

#5 - If project end date is not 30 and is 15 or 16, then how to ensure the last month whenever its is ending should multiply only by those many days and not the full month.
[image]

Unable to find the logic???????

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77508349/split-amount-as-per-days

Comment: Thank you, it is not what I'm looking for - I have a lot of conditions and this link query just splits the amount (I tried incorporating the logic but not working)